# Empty input stream that can be loaded in Properties

Tags: java, spring

I have beans:

```
@Bean(name = "input_bean")
@ConditionalOnResource(resources = "classpath:input.xml")
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CachedProperty.INPUT_FILE_NAME);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "input_bean")
public InputStream getInputStreamDefault() {
    //empty input stream
    return new InputStream() {
        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

If the `input.xml` file exists, the file is loaded into input stream (as bean ), if not the empty input stream is created.

The problem is i am doing it cuz library demands it, and inside that library the input stream is being loaded into property file.

So when i create empty inputstream and properties try to laod it, it results in error.

How can i create placeholder for inputstream, such that it will not throw error when being loaded by properties?

Comment: `when i create empty inputstream and properties try to laod it, it results in error.` What is the error specifically? Please elaborate so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an anoymous inner class just return `InputStream.nullInputStream();`